# Using type "is table of" in a select statement

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to create a select statement to select the fields that were select in a previous select statement, as per below code (using oracle 11g):

```
    Declare 
    type NumberArray IS TABLE OF Number;
    v_medium NumberArray;
    v_medium_final NumberArray := NumberArray(); 
    v_count number;
    type VarcharArray IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(60);
    v_Type VarcharArray
    --Select all Regions and Locality affected by the fault
    cursor Locality_cur is
      Select LocalityCode from AvaFaultLocality where FAULTID=36841 and SITEID=1;
      Locality_rec Locality_cur%ROWTYPE;
    cursor Region_cur is
      Select RegionCode  from avafaultregion where FAULTID=36841 and SITEID=1;
      Region_rec Region_cur%ROWTYPE;
Begin
      v_count := 1; 
      FOR Region_rec IN Region_cur
      LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line(Region_rec.RegionCode);
        Select RECIPIENTMEDIUMID BULK COLLECT into v_medium from  AvaRecipientAreaRegion where RegionCode = Region_rec.RegionCode;

       FOR idx IN 1..v_medium.COUNT LOOP
         v_medium_final.extend(); 
         v_medium_final(v_count) := v_medium(idx); 
         dbms_output.put_line(TO_CHAR(v_medium(idx)));
         v_count:= v_count + 1;
       END LOOP;  
       dbms_output.put_line('End Loop for Region '||Region_rec.RegionCode);     
      END LOOP;
      dbms_output.put_line(TO_CHAR(v_medium_final.count));
      Select MEDIUMTYPECODE BULK COLLECT into v_Type from AvaRecipientMedium where RECIPIENTMEDIUMID in (SELECT * FROM TABLE(v_medium_final)); <--- Line with problem
End;
```

Mainly what I am trying to do is to select the content of all regions, loop this result and get the content of all locality in those regions, and then get all the RecipientMediumID for each locality and add the result in a variable called v_medium_final. This part is working perfectly.
The problem is when I try to use the result of this selection to select the values in a RecipientMedium table where all the values is in the variable v_medium_final.

I try use:

```
Select MEDIUMTYPECODE BULK COLLECT into v_Type from AvaRecipientMedium where RECIPIENTMEDIUMID in (SELECT * FROM TABLE(v_medium_final));
```

or

```
Select MEDIUMTYPECODE BULK COLLECT into v_Type from AvaRecipientMedium where RECIPIENTMEDIUMID in v_medium_final;
```

But I always get the errors:

```
 [Error] Execution (32: 126): ORA-06550: line 32, column 126:
PLS-00642: local collection types not allowed in SQL statements
ORA-06550: line 32, column 120:
PL/SQL: ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item
ORA-06550: line 32, column 7:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

and for the second case:
[Error] Execution (32: 106): ORA-06550: line 32, column 106:

```
PLS-00642: local collection types not allowed in SQL statements
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error indicates, you can't use a local collection type.  You'd need to use a collection type defined at the SQL level.

```
CREATE TYPE NumberArray
    AS TABLE OF NUMBER;

DECLARE
  v_medium NumberArray;
  ...
```

This would require that you have the `CREATE TYPE` privilege and it would mean that your type definition would be visible to anyone with privileges to see it rather than having the scope just of your PL/SQL block.

Personally, I would avoid using `Array` in the name of a collection type that wasn't a `VARRAY` simply because the name could be confusing.  If I see a type `NumberArray`, I would guess that it was defined as a `VARRAY(n) OF NUMBER` rather than a nested table type.  Using a `ntt` suffix for a nested table type would seem more sensible (`create type number_ntt as table of number`).

Comment: Thanks Justin I have been looking for the solution for this for hours, thanks as well for the tips in name convention.

Comment: this solution work fine once I was calling it as a SQL, now I am trying to convert it to a package but I cannot use the create command on it, would you be able to help me once more? Thanks

Comment: @IcaroNZ - I'm not sure that I understand the question.  If you want to use the collection in a SQL statement, the collection type has to be defined in PL/SQL.  So the type definition has to be outside of the package.  You can declare variables in your package that use the SQL type that you have declared but you can't declare the type in PL/SQL and then use it in SQL (at least in your version of Oracle, that restriction is relaxed in 12.1).

Comment: basically what I am trying to do is to create a package that create a list of number and check do a select statement using those numbers in the where clause as Number in ListOfNumbers. I have been working in this for 2 days now, would you be able to point me in the right direction? Thanks

Comment: @IcaroNZ - I'm still not seeing how the package changes anything.  You run a `CREATE TYPE` statement to create the type.  You run a `CREATE PACKAGE` statement to create the package.  You (assuming the package contains procedures or functions) run a `CREATE PACKAGE BODY` statement to create the package body.  Those need to be three separate statements that are creating three separate database objects.

Comment: I see it now, sorry I never use types before, I was thinking I had to declare in the package. Thanks so much is all clean now.